# Moving completed tasks to a new array and then removing them from the new array if the task is unchecked?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am moving tasks to a new array to show activity as tasks are completed. I need to be able to move them out of that array if a task becomes unchecked. Is there a way to reference newly created items by referencing the item is was created from?

Here is a plnkr to show what I have working so far: http://plnkr.co/edit/XnNqej

When I run the isComplete function I add the task to a new array. That's where I think I need to remove it as well.

```
 $scope.isCompleteTask = function(task) {
    if (task.completeTime) {
      task.completeTime = '';
      //would like to delete it from a different list here 
    } else {
      task.completeTime = Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
      $scope.activity.$add(task); //add it here 
    }
    $scope.list.$save(task);
  };
```

Comment: If your questions is "how do I delete the task from the original list?", then the answer is to call `ref.set(null)` on the original location.

Comment: The question is, how do I delete a task that was added to a new array while only having a reference to the original task from which it was created?

Comment: I don't see where the above code snippet of the plunkr are adding the task to a different array. But the answer is always the same: build a ref to the location you want to clear and call `ref.set(null)` on it. We don't your data structure, but there is likely a relation between the two arrays you have in mind: `/root/tasks/-13429781327` vs `/root/completed/-13429781327`. Since a ref is just a URL, you can create one from the other with some string manipulation if needed.

Comment: I only see `tasks` and `posts` in [your data](https://plnkr.firebaseio.com/.json?print=pretty); it's hard to tell exactly what you want here as Frank has already mentioned. Explain the relationship between "original" and "new" and add that to your problem set.

Comment: @Kato Since posting this question I've rethought how I should handle an activity feed. The core of the problem is that I need to display the activity feed in a different order than the regular feed. The plan is to approach it like the 'data relationships' video on egghead.io. In that approach, he maintains a single list and then saves a reference to items relating to specific users instead of saving the item again.